# subclassing from namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.6 and I have an issue when subclassing from namedtuple. For instance:

```
from collections import namedtuple

FieldMetaInfoBase = namedtuple('FieldMetaInfoBase', ['name', 'type', 'special'])

class FieldMetaInfo(FieldMetaInfoBase):
  def __init__(self,
               name,
               type,
               special):

    # throws TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
    super(FieldMetaInfo, self).__init__(name, type, special)

    # is this correct??
    # FieldMetaInfoBase.__init__(name, type, special)


fmi = FieldMetaInfo('a', 'b', 'c')
```

For some reason I cannot init the tuple with some values because I get an error:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or is my solution correct?

```
FieldMetaInfoBase.__init__(name, type, special)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namedtuples are imutable, so you need to use `__new__()` instead of `__init__()`

```
class FieldMetaInfo(FieldMetaInfoBase):
  def __new__(cls, name, type, special):
    self = super(FieldMetaInfo, cls).__new__(cls, name, type, special)
    return self
```

Comment: In Python 3.x you can use `self = super().__new__(cls, name, type, special)` (although the long form shown in this answer works, too). Regardless, you should add a `__slots__ = ()` class attribute to prevent creation of a `__dict__` in the derived class.